# sql records validation in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I like to check the length of a specified fields is x length and available value is a numeric value

i can do this by using two separate case statements like below

```
(case when len(columnA) = 10 then 0 else 1 end)+
(case when IsNumeric(columnA) = 1 then 0 else 1 end)+
(case when len(columnB) = 8 then 0 else 1 end)+
(case when IsNumeric(columnB) = 1 then 0 else 1 end)
```

is there any better approach as i need to this for more than 40 columns and their datatype is varchar and each of the column will have specific length.

using some short cut to reduce above two case statements into one line

Comment: You can create a User defined function and pass the column value, length you want to verify with and move the two case statements (len and isnumeric) into that function. call the function in the select on each column

Comment: IsNumeric does NOT mean the values are actually numbers. Things like 1e4 and $145 will evaluate to true when using IsNumeric.

Comment: is check constraint on the table an option?

Comment: Does the final sum have special significance, e.g. if it is more than 42 the row is okay, or could the whole thing be replaced with `Len( ColumnA ) = 10 and IsNumeric( ColumnA ) and ...`?

Comment: @HABO count of 40 columns must be 0 for making the row good, if the count  is between 1 to 5 we will display which values are giving errors and if the count is more than 5 we say total row record is bad

Comment: @seanlange thanks for your reply, how can we validate if we have only numbers in  a column which is having varchar as datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care that a column is invalid and are less interested in which criteria it failed on then you could just put both criteria into the one case statement as

```
(case when len(columnA) = 10 and IsNumeric(columnA) = 1 then 0 else 1 end)
```

In regards to the issue Sean raised, ISNUMERIC only confirms the value can be converted to a numeric datatype so commas and periods are valid too. you could do a check for any single character that isn't in the range of numbers

```
case when len(columnA) = 10 and ColumnA not like '%[^0-9]%' then 0 else 1 end
```

It is a little ugly because we have to say is not [not in range], so you might want to change the logic a bit.